# Maths in Focus Textbook - Functions

Tags: functions

There are 450 litres of water in a pond and 8 litres of water evaporate out of the pond every hour. After how many hours will the pond be empty?

I've already figured out an equation for the question which is, A=450-8h, A being the pond and h being hours but I'm not sure how to use that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

\begin{align}
A(x) = 450 - 8x, x \in [0, +\infty]
\end{align}
since there are no negative hours. In order to find out when it will empty, just set
\begin{align}
A(x) = 0\\
\implies 450 - 8x = 0\\
\implies 450 = 8x\\
\implies x = \dfrac{450}{8}\\
\implies x = 56.25.
\end{align}
Thus the pool will empty in 56 and a quarter hours.

Comment: Oh thank you so much!